# Cassandra-3.10 on Ubuntu 14.04 malfunctions on machine restart

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-14.04, cassandra-3.0

Here's what I have:
- I installed a cassandra 3.10 version on my Ubuntu 14.04.
- I have it running as a service.
- I've modified cassandra.yaml file to listen to my **node**
- I have a single node.

Everything was working fine; until I had to restart my machine. I hit the command:`sudo service cassandra stop` (I tried restarting my machine without stopping cassandra as well), then restarted my machine. When i got back, and tried to access through cqlsh, I get the following error:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'192.168.2.202': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('192.168.2.202', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

When I look for `nodetool status`, instead of a valid Host ID, I see `null`. I tried `nodetool refresh`, but no luck.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Can you tail the Cassandra system.log when you try to bring it up and post the error lines?

Comment: Did you tried restarting the service?

Comment: @nevsv Yep. Tried restarting the service, didn't work.

Comment: @dilsingi I checked that, and I didn't get any error lines there. All lines were INFO only. Anyways, I purged everything, I downgraded to a more stable version; and everything's working fine now. I believe it's because 3.10 is a release version and not quite stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is now resolved.

I was going through Cassandra's download instructions to check if I had messed something up during my installation.

Then I came across this information: "**Even numbered versions are bug fixes and new releases and features, possibly buggy (with existing bugs from new features); odd numbered versions are bug fixes to its immediate predecessor**".

Apparently, this is something called the "tick-tock" release.

I believe that was the problem - a bad version. I just checked it out with the now-latest Cassandra version - 3.11 (odd == less buggy), and it's working perfectly. Lesson learned - never deploy the latest Cassandra version in production if the version is even!

References:
https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-2-2-3-0-and-beyond
https://www.pythian.com/blog/cassandra-version-production/